# Insert difference of two datetimes into another table with MySQL

Tags: mysql

I need some help with this, I need to Insert the result of the difference between two datetimes into another table. This is the Query to get the difference:

```
SELECT TIMEDIFF (comments.finalizacion_fase,cutlog.started)AS DIF
FROM cutlog_a cutlog INNER JOIN comments_cutlog_a 
comments ON cutlog.id=comments.id_log_cutlog_a
```

But I dont know how to do the rest properly, I already searched for INSERT INTO but I cant figure how to adapt it to my needs.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Use `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` syntax:

```
INSERT INTO otherTable (column)
SELECT TIMEDIFF (comentarios.finalizacion_fase, cutlog.started)
FROM metlab.cutlog_junta cutlog
INNER JOIN comentarios_cutlog_junta comentarios
    ON cutlog.id = comentarios.id_log_cutlog_junta
```

Note that your current select only has one column of output, hence I only insert one column above.  But you may insert as many columns as you wish into the other table.

Comment: damm, I feel dumb, btw how can I set the format of the result of the insert to hours and minutes, besides can I just put this like this into a trigger?

Comment: Why do want to deal with hours/minutes rather than a single unit (e.g. seconds)?  Yes, this query should run inside a trigger.

Comment: Im noob for this btw I put this on a trigger and it works but I have a problem, for example
1 2 3 4 5
those are the five time differences I need to insert, but when I run the trigger it works like this
Insert difference 1
insert difference 1 and 2
insert difference 1 2 and 3
and so, how can  I fix that?

Comment: I can't help you based on that comment.  If you have a new problem with a trigger, consider asking another question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46893381/issue-with-trigger-inserting-same-results-mysql ready